How to dynamic import in Nuxt 3 without preloading the bundle?
I'm trying to dynamic import firebase-auth module in Nuxt 3, however the build always preload firebase-auth despite dynamic import, sample code below:
onMounted(async () => {
  if (Math.random() > 100) {
    const { getAuth } = await import('firebase/auth')

    console.log('getAuth() imported')
  }
})

I don't expect the firebase-auth to preload as the if statement will never be executed.
A minimal reproduction is available at:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-preloaded-dynamic-import

Also posted to https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/18376 as it might be related.
Thanks!

The problem has been resolved in https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/17936.
It seems the underlying cause is in rollup code splitting and manualChunks.
